# How to get "hx-params" from htmx post request?

Tags: javascript, python, flask, htmx

I have a JavaScript function that generates buttons for `seats` and each `seat` gets an `hx-post`, `hx-trigger`, and `hx-params`. In the params, the seat id (for example "0-0" or "12-5") is generated. I want to get the params in the POST request `/select_seat` and print it. My code returns `"None"`

JS:

```js
const seat = document.createElement("button");
seat.innerHTML = `${(c + 1) + (r * 6)} - ${(ic + 1) + (ir * 8)}`;
seat.setAttribute("hx-params", `${(c + 1) + (r * 6)}-${(ic + 1) + (ir * 8)}`);
seat.setAttribute("hx-trigger", 'click');
seat.setAttribute("hx-post", '/select_seat');
```

Htmx:

```html
<button hx-params="1-1" hx-trigger="click" hx-post="/select_seat" class="seat">1 - 1</button>
```

Flask:

```py
@app.route('/select_seat', methods=['POST'])
def your_route():
    print(request.data)  # Print the raw data received
    
    htmx_data = request.json
    
    if htmx_data:
        hx_params = htmx_data.get('params', {}).get('hx-params', None)
        
        if hx_params:
            print(hx_params)
            return jsonify({'status': 'success'})
    
    return jsonify({'status': 'error'})
```

See the Flask code above.

Comment: @MaikeruDev The exact code you provided, returned<button hx-params="seat=1-1" hx-trigger="click" hx-post="/select_seat" class="seat">{
  "status": "error"
}
</button>

Answer (score 1):

`hx-params` is not used to pass values, but to filter specific inputs to be sent, or not, with the request.

What you are looking for is `hx-vals` https://htmx.org/attributes/hx-vals/

Try this:

```html
<button hx-vals='{"seat": "1-1"}' hx-trigger="click" hx-post="/select_seat" class="seat">1 - 1</button>
```

Then you can read the `seat` value in your post request.